# can connect to ipv6 access point, but not communicate with devices

Tags: linux, router, ipv6, wireless-access-point, radvd

I am attempting to run a local ipv6 network and have gone through a number of tutorials, but with limited success.  I'm running a server on the router/access point and it is the only device I need to access. Most of the tutorials I've read instruct you how to make an internet addressable ipv6 router which goes beyond my needs and I can't always follow exactly because of this.  As far as I can tell everything is setup correctly, I can even see neighbors, but are unable to ping the neighbors I see from the router or the router from a connected device, further attempts at access are similarly futile, http requests and so on.

I have opened a wireshark, and see only DNS and ICMPV6 protocol messages.

The access point is a pi running raspian where I am trying to connect my windows 7 laptop to.  I've included a lot of information below because it is all correct as far as I can tell, so I'm sure I'm missing something.

**On the access point**:

ifconfig

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:6d:20:38
          inet6 addr: 1234:5678:90ab:cdef::1/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::76da:38ff:fe6d:2038/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: bbbb::1/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2275 errors:0 dropped:392 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:102 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:18103 (17.6 KiB)  TX bytes:18658 (18.2 KiB)
```

sysctl.conf

```
...
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
...
```

The interface is setup as:

```
iface wlan0 inet6 static
address 1234:5678:90ab:cdef::1
netmask 64
```

hostapd:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=rtl871xdrv
ssid=ssid
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=passphrase
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

radvd.conf

```
interface wlan0 {
  AdvSendAdvert on;
  prefix 1234:5678:90ab:cdef::/64 {
    AdvOnLink on;
    AdvAutonomous on;
    AdvRouterAddr on;
  };
};
```

dnsmasq:

```
bind-interfaces
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=1234:5678:90ab:cdef::2,1234:5678:90ab:cdef::10,12h
no-hosts
enable-ra
addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.dnsmasq
```

ip -6 neigh show

```
fe80::76da:38ff:fe6d:2038 dev wlan0 lladdr 74:da:38:6d:20:38 router STALE
fe80::9118:7ac1:f129:8544 dev wlan0 lladdr 10:4a:7d:c6:d7:f2 STALE
1234:5678:90ab:cdef:124:752f:f01b:2570 dev wlan0 lladdr 10:4a:7d:c6:d7:f2 STALE
```

ip -6 route show:

```
1234:5678:90ab:cdef::/64 dev wlan0  proto kernel  metric 256
aaaa::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256
bbbb::/64 dev wlan0  proto kernel  metric 256
fd01::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev wlan0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe90::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe91::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256
```

**On the windows end device**

ipconfig:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 1234:5678:90ab:cdef:9118:7ac1:f129:8544
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 1234:5678:90ab:cdef:e13b:c2d1:1685:bd01
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9118:7ac1:f129:8544%12
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::76da:38ff:fe6d:2038%12
```

From my understanding, if the end device is showing up as a neighbor on the router they should be able to communicate.  Now it is showing as a stale connection, but even when in the past it has been listed as REACHABLE, I have been unable to ping it.

Comment: If your IPv6 traffic is only to be used locally and not to be routed on the internet, then you are supposed to use RFC 4193 addresses such as `fdef:0142:9c0b::/48`.

Comment: Thanks,  I haven't seen that in any of the special address tables I've looked at.  So Basically change 1234:5678:90ab:cdef... to fdef:0142:9c0b::/48 in all of the configs then?